# User Based Exception program not working

Tags: python

This code does not work. Please tell what the error is....

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self,mssg):
        self.mssg = mssg

class InputError(Error):
    def __init__(self,val):
        super("Input Error")
        print val
```

Now I write in other part of my program

```
a = raw_input("Enter a number from 0-9: ")
if (ord(a)>47 and ord(a)<58):
    pass
else:
    raise InputError(a)
```

Now when I pass 'a' I get  `super expected a type but got a string` I just want to pass that message to the base class and display it along with the wrong value.

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) incorrectly. The proper way is:

```
class InputError(Error):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super(InputError, self).__init__(val)
        print val
```

Comment: It seems tricker, but it follows with other Python idioms.  Just as methods require you to explicitly pass `self` (which is the current instance), `super` requires you to explicitly pass in the current class.

Answer (score 0):

[`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) is used to access methods of a superclass that have been overridden in the subclass, not to instantiate the superclass with arguments.

What you appear to be trying to do is something like:

```
class InputError(Error):
    def __init__(self,val):
        super(InputError).__init__("Input Error")
        print val
```

although this isn't necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Please tell how do you do it then.... lets say that there is a variable in base class and since it is common to all you want to just pass the value from the subclass what do you do??

Answer (score 0):

[`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) is supposed to be called like this:

```
class InputError(Error):
    def __init__(self,val):
        super(InputError, self).__init__("Input Error")
        print val
```

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a python builtin which takes the *type* of an object as its argument, not some (arbitrary) string, as you seem to have done. You probably mean

```
 super(InputError, self).__init__("Input Error")
```

[In Python 3.x, this can just be `super().__init__("Input Error")`]

Note that because of the name of your exception is already `InputError`, it's not clear what the string message adds to it...

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super) and the python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: Yes It does .... Thanks a lot and I was referring to your saying that I am passing "Input Error"